# Structure sheaf of affine variety consists of noetherian rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X\subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$ be an affine variety.

The local ring of $X$ at $p\in X$, given by $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}=\{f\in k(X):f \text{ regular at } p\}$ is noetherian because it is a localization of $k[X]$.

If $U\subseteq X$ is open, let $\mathcal{O}_X(U)=\bigcap_{p\in U}\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$. Is this ring noetherian as well?

Comment: $O_X(U)$ is also a localization of $k[X]$.

Comment: @DenisNardin Are you saying $\mathcal{O}_X(U)=\{\frac{f}{g}\mid f,g\in k[X], g(p)\neq 0\forall p\in U\}$?. Because this is not true. Consider $X=V(xy-zw)\subseteq\mathbb{A}^4$, and $U=U_y\cup U_w$, where $U_y=\{(x,y,z,w)\mid y\neq 0\}$ and $U_w=\{(x,y,z,w)\mid w\neq 0\}$. Then there is $h\in\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ such that $h=\frac{z}{y}$ in $U_y$ and $h=\frac{x}{w}$ in $U_w$, but there is no global expression for $h$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @Fan Zheng is absolutely right: this is a very interesting and highly non-trivial question.  I'm upvoting it right now.

Comment: I don't believe that $\mathcal O_X(U) $ is noetherian. Beware that the accepted answer below is false.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I had already asked this question at mathSE, but couldn't get an answer. I asked it then at MO, where everyone regarded it as trivial. Now that they migrated this, there are two copies of the same question, both with valuable comments. What should I do?

Comment: I started a bounty for my original question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1696350/structure-sheaf-consists-of-noetherian-rings I am going to delete this version of the question in a couple of days.

Comment: Dear Marco, the question is definitely not trivial and unfortunately both sites are infested with incompetent, arrogant users who seem to take pleasure in closing and  (in the case of MO) migrating questions to a "lesser" site. In  your case one of the migrators is a highly competent algebraic geometer but I still think he was wrong to  vote for  migrating    the question. For what it's worth, let me repeat that I am almost  (but not quite!) sure that there exist cases where $\mathcal O_X(U)$ is not noetherian.

Comment: Dear Marco, I think the best you can do is to evoke your problem on metaMO and hope that someone will help you there.

Comment: Dear @GeorgesElencwajg You were right. I asked professor Ravi Vakil, he told me he gives a counterexample in section 19.11.13 of his notes: https://math216.wordpress.com/

Comment: Dear Marco, Professor Vakil's example is very interesting but his $X$ is not affine, contrary to what you require.. Could you ask him if his example can be modified (maybe by deleting one or several  points in the elliptic curve $E$) so as to obtain an $X\subset \mathbb A^n$ ?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Is it possible to migrate it back to mathoverflow?

Comment: Dear @Fan Zheng: I am all for that but I have no power to implement that. I think Marco should try to do that.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, let me just note that this question has been [re-crossposted](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/235607/structure-sheaf-of-affine-variety-consists-of-noetherian-rings-again) on Mathoverflow and got an answer there.